# Bound the $\infty$-norm of the eigenvector of the second minimum eigenvalue of normalized Laplacian from below

Tags: graph-theory, sp.spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I meet the above problem while reading a paper. The problem can be stated as below.

> Consider an undirected graph $G$. Let $\mathbf{v}$ be a vector such that $\mathbf{D}^{1/2}\mathbf{v}$ is the eigenvector of the normalized Laplacian of $G$ corresponding to the second minimum eigenvalue. Prove that $\left\| \mathbf{v} \right\|_{\infty} := \max_{i} \left| \mathbf{v}_i \right|$ could be as low as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{v\in V}d_v}}$.

My question is:

1. How to prove the claim above? (The paper neither gave a proof nor referred it to some earlier origin.)
2. Is there any literature rich of properties of $\mathbf{v}$ mentioned above?

Any advice is appreciated.